# About updating values in multiple check boxes

Tags: javascript, html

I have created multiple checkboxes using a script in an HTML file. 
I want to updates the checkboxes using name based on a condition like the below.

```
Checkboxes[I].checked = true;
```

But it's throwing an error. 
Can you please suggest a way to solve this issue out.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide your HTML and an example of what you tried, javascript-wise. Click the EDIT button at bottom, arrow down to the bottom of your question, and press `Ctrl` + `M` - then add your code in the appropriate boxes.

Comment: _But it's throwing an error_ And sharing that error will be more useful than mentioning that an error is thrown.

Comment: Please also show the code where you declare the `Checkboxes` array and also show us the loop which this statement you mentioned, is being contained if there is

Answer (score 0):

for this purpose I will try to answer you, I have two options, by class or tag name, may if you want to use Jquery its also nice. I prepare an example for you, I hope that this one helps you, greetings

```js
function toggleA() {
    var elm = document.getElementsByClassName('chx');
    
  for(var i = 0; i < elm.length; i++) {
      elm[i].checked = !elm[i].checked;
       // alert(elm[i].value);
  }
  
}

function toggleB() {
  var elm = $(".chx").prop("checked")
  
  $(".chx").prop( "checked", !elm ); 
}

function toggleC() {
    var elm = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    
  for(var i = 0; i < elm.length; i++) {
    if(elm[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'checkbox') {
      elm[i].checked = !elm[i].checked;
       // alert(elm[i].value);
    }
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" onclick="toggleA()">Toggle A</button>&nbsp;
<button id="btn" onclick="toggleB()">Toggle B</button>&nbsp;
<button id="btn" onclick="toggleC()">Toggle C</button>&nbsp;

<br><br>
<label>
    <input id="check-a" class = "chx" onchange="alert('Changed A!')" type="checkbox"> A
</label>
    <br><br>
<label>
    <input id="check-b" class = "chx" onchange="alert('Changed B!')" type="checkbox"> B
</label>
    <br><br>
<label>
    <input id="check-jq" class = "chx" onchange="alert('Changed JQ!')" type="checkbox"> JQ
</label>
    <br><br>
<label>
    <input id="check-c" class = "chx" onchange="alert('Changed C!')" type="checkbox"> C
</label>
```